# Android: Difference between INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL, INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY, INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

What do the three constants :

`INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL`,

`INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY` and

`INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE`

specify in the `NotificationListenerService`?

Also what notifications does priority interruption filter covers?

The android docs doesn't clearly mention it, though one can get some ideas from the name, can someone provide a clear answer?

Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are used by the NotificationManager to change the notification policy introduced in Android M.

[The docs actually are pretty clear](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) so I'll just re-iterate them:

**INTERRUPTION_FILTER_ALL** - Normal interruption filter - no notifications are suppressed.

**INTERRUPTION_FILTER_NONE** - No interruptions filter - all notifications are suppressed and all audio streams (except those used for phone calls) and vibrations are muted.

**INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY** - Interruption filter constant - Priority interruption filter - all notifications are suppressed except those that match the priority criteria. Some audio streams are muted. See priorityCallSenders, priorityCategories, priorityMessageSenders to define or query this criteria. Users can additionally specify packages that can bypass this interruption filter.

Basically they just allow you to set the filters on which notifications you wish to suppress (or not suppress).